# How to localize page title with Spring and Tiles2?

Tags: spring, localization, internationalization, tiles

I have a Spring application which uses Tiles for the view tier. So all my pages definitions look like this:

```
<definition name="main.page" template="/tiles/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Page Title"/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/tiles/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="welcome.page" extends="main.page">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Main Page"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/welcome.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

The code which sets page title is:

```
<title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title>
```

I would like to localize with Spring tag:

```
<spring:message>
```

Are there any "best practices" how to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you ever tried to put the message key in you tiles variable and use it as key for the spring message tag.

Something like that:

```
<definition name="welcome.page" extends="main.page">
    <put-attribute name="titleKey" value="page.main.title"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/welcome.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

jsp:

```
<set var"titleKey"><tiles:getAsString name="titleKey"/></set>
<title><spring:message code=${titleKey} /></title>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I tried <title><spring:message code="<tiles:getAsString name="titleKey"/>" /></title>
and it didn't work out. Thanks.

Comment: @Pavel yeah that wouldn't work as you couldn't really embed the tiles tag as an attribute ... it would get passed as a literal to the tag.

Comment: Good solution - the only other thing I did is replace `page.main.title` with `{1}.title` when using [wildcards in Apache tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/wildcard.html).  It saves you a bit of time with configuration.

Answer (score 6):

The previous answer contains several little mistakes

tiles.xml

```
<definition name="main" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="titleKey" value="main.title" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp" />
</definition>
```

jsp (/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp)

```
<c:set var="titleKey"><tiles:getAsString name="titleKey"/></c:set>
<title><spring:message code="${titleKey}"></spring:message> </title>
```